# AchartEngine: How to use TimeSeries with two different scales

Tags: android, achartengine

As TimeSeries Construstor of AchartEngine API take only string as argument and have no other argument to pass as a scale argument. So how I will use it with two different scales

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you don't try to use `TimeSeries` for multiple scales charting.

You would better build a regular multiple scale line chart, set timestamps on the X axis and set your custom labels.

```
// disable the default labels
renderer.setXLabels(0);
// add your formatted dates, several of these calls
renderer.addXTextLabel(x, "formatted date");
```

Comment: Looks good! but i want to keep 7 dates as fixed by default on my screen. Any suggestion ?

Comment: You will have to listen for Pan and Zoom events and always update the labels. Remove the old ones and add new ones.

Comment: How you are associating Pan and Zoom with x-axis limits. I am talking about x-axis min and max limits. It should be initially form date1 to date7 on my screen. Please correct me if I am wrong. Thanks Dan for your cooperation

Comment: it could not solved my problem of x-axis limits. Can you give me sample example code?

Comment: You can read the x axis limits using renderer.getXAxisMin() and ...Max().

Comment: I want to set XAxisMin(date1) and XAxisMax(date7), but when i use renderer.setXLabels(0), it overrides all that functionality, mean both in parallel not working. Can you please post sample. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I would like to propose a simpler solution.

The reason that you can't have multiple scale groups with TimeSeries is simply because the authors forgot (or didn't feel the need) to add the necessary constructor to allow you to set which scale group the series should belong to.  TimeSeries is a subclass of XYSeries and is incredibly simple (find the source [here](https://code.google.com/p/achartengine/source/checkout)).  The only special thing it does is give you an add method that takes a Date rather than a double.  In fact, the add method in TimeSeries just makes the following call which passes in the x value as the millisecond time:

```
super.add(x.getTime(), y);
```

So the easiest way to accomplish what you want to do is to use a TimeChart, but instead of using a TimeSeries, use an XYSeries and just pass your dates in as milliseconds (just like TimeSeries does!).  With this approach, you don't need to mess with the custom x axis labels.

Another approach might be to just write your own subclass of XYSeries.

Hopefully, the necessary constructor will be added to TimeSeries in the future so none of this will be necessary.

**Better solution**
I found that it is better to just sub-class XYSeries with my own TimeSeries with the necessary constructor to support the scale group.  This is because there is a padding value in the XYSeries which is overridden in TimeSeries.  So, using the XYSeries for time can have problems due to that padding value.  Here is the simple subclass that I'm using (notice the getPadding method returning 1, you need to have that):

```
    private class MyTimeSeries extends XYSeries {

    public MyTimeSeries(String title, int scaleNumber) {
        super(title, scaleNumber);
    }

    public synchronized void add(Date x, double y) {
        super.add(x.getTime(), y);
    }

    @Override
    protected double getPadding(double x) {
        return 1;
    }
}
```